# iOS using nsstring from class in UIViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring

I've been bashing my head against this for a week solid, I'm sure its been answered before but in all my research i'm just confusing myself more and more.

I'm just simply trying to use an NSString from a class (BBDate) in a UILabel in my main UIViewController.

BBDate.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface BBDate : NSObject {
  NSString *dateString;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *dateString;
@end
```

BBDate.m

```
//just a simple date creation and formatting to try to learn this technique
#import "BBDate.h"
@implementation BBDate  
@synthesize  dateString;

- (void)createDate; {
NSDate* date = [NSDate date];
//Create the dateformatter object
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
//Set the required date format
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];
//Get the string date
NSString *string = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
//Display on the console
    NSLog (@"%@",string); 
    //set variable
   dateString = string;
   }
   @end
```

UIViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "BBDate.h"

@interface BBFirstViewController : UIViewController {

UILabel *dateToday;
BBDate *bbDate;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *dateToday;
@property (nonatomic, retain) BBDate *bbDate;
@end
```

UIViewController.m

```
#import "BBFirstViewController.h"
#import "BBDate.h"
@implementation BBFirstViewController
@synthesize dateToday, bbDate;
...
//for testing i'm just using viewdidload
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
dateToday.text = bbDate.dateString;
NSLog(@"%@", bbDate.dateString);
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize bbDate for one thing and create a date:

```
bbDate = [[BBDate alloc] init];
[bbDate createDate];
```

Put that before:

```
dateToday.text = bbDate.dateString;
```

Also:

```
- (void)createDate; {
```

Get rid of the semicolon:

```
- (void)createDate {
```

In your createDate method:

```
dateString = string;
```

Should be:

```
self.dateString = string;
```

Plus you probably are not going to need the NSDateFormatter outside your method so at the end of it say:

```
[formatter release];
```

Comment: awesome thanks a ton.  I knew i had to alloc/init the class but wasn't sure the syntax and I hadn't caught the errant semicolon.  also i'm using ARC so I don't need to release objects.  I also had to add - (void)createDate to the BBDate.h for the vc to see it.  thanks again, I finally understand!